# How to pass an object as a param to ng-click with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

I used HTML snippet on javascript to pass an object to a function but it didn't work.

```
var obj = { LocationID: location.LocationID, OrderID: c.ID };
str += `<div class="col-md-9">${c.OrderCode}</div>
<div class="col-md-1" ng-click="$ctrl.iconClicked($event, 'remove', ${obj})"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:#FF0000" title="Remove order"></i></div></div>`;
```

The param only accepts value.

```
str += `<div class="col-md-9">${c.OrderCode}</div>
<div class="col-md-1" ng-click="$ctrl.iconClicked($event, 'remove', ${location.LocationID}, ${c.OrderID})"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:#FF0000" title="Remove order"></i></div></div>`;
```